# How to evaluate the tightness of a bound on a function?

Tags: optimization, proof-techniques, lower-bounds, upper-bound

I recently submitted a paper where in part of the paper I derived a bound on a function (note it is an upper bound). The benefit of the bound is that it is much less complex to compute in contrast to the actual value of the function. So, the bound can be used as a cost for optimization instead of the actual value of the function. However, I received a comment that I did not include a proof for the tightness of the bound.

I'm not exactly sure what is meant by this. I did numerical experiments demonstrating how the bound is related to the actual value of the function (i.e., showing the difference between the bound and the actual value), but I understand this is specific to the experimental setup. Is there a standard procedure for evaluating the tightness of a bound on a function in general? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the tightness of the bound is not critical to get a good solution, the comment was irrelevant. Otherwise, the reviewer is right. There is no general technique to obtain approximations.

Comment: The derivative of the bound is more important than the actual bound. Based on experiments, the bound proves to be a good alternative leading to similar results. The only reason for using the bound is to approximate the cost, but I’m not sure how to determine a more theoretical justification of the closeness of the bound and/derivatives an actual value.

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate tightness of a bound on a function, you need to find both the upper and lower bounds. Finding an upper bound on the function is good but it leaves the possibility that the actual function might be asymptotically better than the computed upper bound.

For example, suppose the actual function is $f(x) = n + n/2 + n/3 +\dotsc + 1$. Then, one can trivially find an upper bound on $f(x)$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= n + n/2 + n/3 +\dotsc + 1 \\
&\leq n + n + \dotsc + n \\
&\leq n^2 \\
&= O(n^2)
\end{align}
$$

Now, how would you know $f(x)$ is not $O(n)$ or $O(\sqrt{n})$ or anything better than $O(n^2)$? Therefore, you need a matching lower bound. For that you need [Big Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) notation. In other words, you need to show that $f(x) = \Omega(n^2)$ so that it does not leave the possibility of $f(x)$ being $O(n)$ or $O(\sqrt{n})$, etc.

Interestingly, the upper bound of $O(n^2)$ for $f(x)$ is not tight. The tight bound in fact is $O(n \log n)$. That is, $n + n/2 + n/3 + \dotsc + 1$ can also be lower bounded by $\Omega(n \log n)$. This is beacuse the $n^{th}$ harmonic number $H_{n}$ is lower and upper bounded by $\log n$ (see [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/toolkit13/lecture01-anonymous.pdf#page=4) for reference). Thus, we have $f(x) = O(n \log n)$ and $f(x) = \Omega(n \log n)$.